# JUnit Exception Handling Test

Tags: java, junit

In DAO class

```
catch (Exception e) {

        throw new DaoException(e);
}
```

In Junit Class

```
@Test
public void testClass() throws DaoException {
    try {
        doThrow(Exception.class).when(testDAO).getTestData();
        testDAO.getTestData();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

Unable to cover DaoException.Could you please help me to cover DAOException in JUNIT.

Comment: can't you send bad / wrong data to force the exception?

Comment: What is the code of method getTestData?

Answer (score 2):

You should NOT enclose it in try catch block within your JUnit.
Looks like you want to verify whether DaoException class being thrown.

Since you are already using JUnit 4, below is the syntax for it:

```
@Test(expected=DaoException.class)
public void testClass() {
    doThrow(Exception.class).when(testDAO).getTestData();
    testDAO.getTestData();
}
```

The snippet above will pass the test if it throws DaoException.